# How can I configure my CMake project to install dependency packages?

Tags: linux, unix, cmake, apt, vorbis

I am trying to distribute a recent project - but need a way to download a few dependencies if the target OS is `UNIX`:

```
  if (UNIX)
      message("Detected Linux OS - install required")
      #Install libs here
  endif (UNIX)
```

I don't want to use a system command like apt since naturally different systems will have different package managers - is there a way I can install apt packages (such as `libvorbis-dev`) directly?

Comment: "is there a way I can install apt packages (such as `libvorbis-dev`) directly?" - Not sure what do you mean by "directly". **Direct** installation of a package on, say, Ubuntu is to use `apt`. If you ask whether CMake provides a **cross-platform wrapper** around distro-specific package installation, then no, CMake doesn't provide such wrappers.

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for, in which case is it acceptable just to attempt to install with APT for any unix system (the point being not all use it) - because I'm not sure how else I can install these dependencies cleanly otherwise

Comment: "in which case is it acceptable just to attempt to install with APT for any unix system" - This is very **subjective**. I find that unconditional using of `apt` is confusing. Normally, a CMake project only **checks** whether required functionality is provided by the system. If the functionality is not provided, then it is correct to emit the error. In the README of your project  you could specify which functionality do you need and how this functionality could be achieved e.g. on Ubuntu.

Comment: so do you want an answer that works with multiple system package managers? or without using system package managers at all? If you want the latter, it will probably depend on specific details of what library it is and where their binaries can be found (ex. if they can be found on a non-system package manager like vcpkg or conan).

Comment: @user honestly whichever is most convenient! I assume that the latter is easier to achieve however - On further research vcpkg does indeed provide all the libraries I need -   in which case should I simply state that as a required package manager before installation? I guess that is a reasonable request for UNIX systems...

Comment: **Don't do that!** Just leave it to the one who builds your package. This is just not your task! Your task (in `CMakeLists.txt`) is to detect the build environment: if everything needed for the build is present). Setting up all dependencies is the task for the one who builds your project using whatever package manager he has in his OS/distro. It's just not your business to be a package manager... Leave it to real package managers (apt, yum, dnf, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that all the libraries your project needs are [on vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html), I'd suggest to just use vcpkg. You can read about how to use vcpkg with CMake in [their docs on that topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration).

You could also take a look at [Conan Center](https://conan.io/center/) and see if it has the libraries you want.

If you want the dependencies to be built from scratch instead of using a package manager that downloads pre-built binaries, you can take a look at [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) (and see also [CMake's "Using Dependencies Guide"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/using-dependencies/index.html)).

Using a package manager might be simpler than trying to shoehorn system package manager installation commands into your CMake configuration phase (which is a pretty unconventional thing to do. Usually when it comes to packages from system package managers, CMake configurations just expect that the package has already been installed, with documentation telling build-users to manually install dependencies however they wish, with the CMake configuration just searching for installed packages using [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). I think your users might even find it to be a bad kind of surprising if running configuration for your project suddenly requests installing
a system package).